# How to find & return a value from a SortedSet (or what other container should I use)?

Tags: c#

Forgive me if I'm not using any of the C# jargon perfectly; I'm still somewhat new to C#.

Central to my application is a data type with a globally unique name, with a list of references (names) to other objects of the same type. I need to be able to look up these objects based on their name.

In the initial implementation of my application, all program logic was separate from the data type; essentially my data type was a methodless struct, and I used a `SortedDictionary` to look up the objects:

```
public class MyClass // each 'MyClass' object is named, but doesn't know its own name
{
    public List<string> myFriends = new List<string>(); // list of names
    // ... a bunch of other public data ...
}

// A lookup table of MyClass objects: name --> MyClass object in O(log n) time
public class MyTable : SortedDictionary<string, MyClass> { }
```

(I wrapped `SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>` in an otherwise empty class since it seems that sadly C# doesn't have `typedef`, and I don't want to have to keep passing around `SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>` arguments between methods. Is that a typical C# programming practice???)

OK, so here's the problem:

I want to move some of the program logic into `MyClass`, making the program itself simpler. But to do that, `MyClass` objects will need to know their names:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myName;
    public List<string> myFriends = new List<string>(); // list of names
    // ... a bunch of other public data ...
}
```

But if each object knows its own name, what's the sense in using a `SortedDictionary` for `MyTable` if the key of the dictionary is the name? It seems like a `SortedSet` would make more sense then, if I just implement the `IComparable<>` interface for `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>
{
    public string myName;
    public List<string> myFriends = new List<string>(); // list of names
    // ... a bunch of other data, some public, some private ...
    public int CompareTo(MyClass that)
    {
        return this.myName.CompareTo(that.myName);
    }
}

// A lookup table of MyClass objects: name --> MyClass object in O(log n) time
public class MyTable : SortedSet<MyClass> { }
```

That way there's no possibility of a `MyClass` object's name not matching the key used to look it up in a `MyTable`. But I can't figure out how to find & return the value of an element; `SortedSet.Contains()` isn't sufficient, since the value of an element isn't the same as the key for looking it up.

Is there a way to get the value of an element in a `SortedSet<MyClass>`, or do I just need to go back to using `SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason it needs to be sorted? How many elements will be in the collection? Are you sure you need the efficiency of a hash table (implemented by `Dictionary`) or is a linear search for matching elements acceptable?

Comment: @JackA. - An O(1) hashed container would be better, but O(log n) performance is acceptable and I prefer my output to be sorted without me having to explicitly sort it prior to printing, so I chose `SortedDictionary` in the beginning. The whole app runs in about 0.5 seconds so using a hashed container wouldn't make much difference. A linear search container, however, would not be good.

Comment: @JackA. - Do you have a solution in O(n) time that doesn't use LINQ? If so, maybe I can adapt it to O(log n) time? Ideally a `MyTable` would have an indexer implementation that takes a string and returns the `MyClass` object, just the way a `SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>` would do.

Comment: You might be surprised how fast things happen when done strictly in memory. I would suggest trying the simplest possible approach first and only optimize if the performance is unacceptable. The simplest approach I can think of is a `List<>` as the collection, sort each time an item is added, and use the `Find` method to look up by key.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to get a value from `SortedSet<MyClass>` with even `O(log(n))` time complexity. You actually may do it with Linq extension SingleOrDefault equality predicate but it will take `O(n)` time in worse case which I assume is not appropriate.

`Dictionary<string, MyClass>` or `SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>` seem to perfectly suit you requirements and offer very efficient way to find a value by key. The operation has roughly `O(1)` time complexity.

You can also consider supporting two these data structures in parallel.